# Use contextual filter and path arguments

Tags: 8, views

I have a view, displayed on /user/%user/library, which shows a list of nodes.

> [image: screenshot]

I want to add a contextual filter, for example field_premium_id.

I tried to add the two arguments there, but *%user* is not available on contextual filters.

```php
$args[0] = $uid;
$args[1] = $field_premium_id_arg; // ['6921384+466555']

$view->setArguments($args);
```

When I only use one argument, *%user* is replaced by field_premium_id_arg.

My goal is to show certain nodes on /user/%user/library basing on the user ID and a custom node field.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you have two arguments and you provide only one, then %user being replaced by field_premium_id_arg is the default behaviour. You can use default values for %user to fix this issue. It will be better if you add screenshots of your view UI to make the question clear.

Comment: @SandeshYadav, the user ID is not avaiblae for this view